# Download email attachment and upload S3 bucket AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-api, amazon-ses

I have a web app hosted on aws under free tier limit. What I want to achieve is that whenever I received an email, i want the system to download its attachment(will be images only), upload that image to s3 and save the image id in database with email's sender email address. I don't want to use zapier api etc, I want to code it my self. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really depends upon how your email is hosted.

You could use [Receive Email with Amazon Simple Email Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email.html).

The flow could then either be:

- SES -> S3 -> Trigger Event -> AWS Lambda function, *or*
- SES -> SNS -> AWS Lambda function

You would then need to write a Lambda function to do the processing you described.

If, on the other hand, your email is being hosted elsewhere, then you will need a mechanism to trigger some code when an email is received (somehow on your email system) or a scheduled Lambda function to poll the email system to see whether new mail is available.

Comment: Thanks. It helped a lot.

Comment: Now how do i save a jpg file to s3 if i have the file contents in raw form? 
I mean i need to write the buffer string ( contents of attachment) using file stream. 
I have image data in this form:
https://screenshots.firefox.com/3BFsPhzECQNY47NT/us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com#

Comment: The easiest way is to save it as a `.jpg` in the `/tmp` directory, then use [`upload_file()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_file) to copy it to S3. This way, you do not need to use streams with S3.

Comment: Successfully achieved everything through your help.

Comment: @OsamaKhalid Do you mind sharing the link to the code for the lambda function you used to achieve this.

Comment: @hiits100rav I don't have access to that code right now, it was long ago. But if you have any questions I can help you out, it was a really simple one though after I figured out the solution